# Diff file hierarchies between Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, tree, cygwin, diff

I've got a file hierarchy tree on a linux host that I can access via SSH (WinSCP)
Its about 160 GB in size.
I have slightly different file hierarchy tree on my Windows laptop (has Cygwin).
I'd like to see the differences in filenames and sizes, preferrably checksums.
Is there a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28Unix%29) utility variant that also lists a checksum and size.
This way, I can diff the outputs.
Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rsync --checksum --delete --dry-run` to let rsync compare the checksums and show which files it would transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Would a source control tool be acceptable?  Make the pertinent directory structure a `git` repository.  Then you can `git sync` to bring them into synch, and do the diffs after the fact.